# Similar functionality to CLOCK_MONOTONIC in Windows (and Windows Embedded CE)

Tags: c++, windows, system-clock

I have some C++ Windows code which needs to compute time intervals. For that, it uses [GetCurrentFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914579.aspx) if it detects that is running in WinCE and [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for other Windows platforms. However, if I'm not mistaken, this might be vulnerable to system clock manipulations (i.e. someone changing the system clock would make the measured time intervals unreliable).

Is there something similar to UNIX's CLOCK_MONOTONIC for these platforms (both WinCE and the other Windows platforms) which would make use of a monotonically increasing counter and not the system clock?

Comment: Use GetTickCount() or QueryPerformanceCounter().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up using [`GetTickCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms908465(v=msdn.10)), which worked just fine.

As per Microsoft's documentation:

> The number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was
> started indicates success.

It is a monotonic counter, which is what I was looking for. The granularity of the returned value depends on the hardware, but seems to be enough for my purposes in the hardware I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

`std::chrono::steady_clock` is monotonic and not vulnerable to system time changes. I don't know if Microsoft supports C++11 for WinCE though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even if they did I am stuck with C++03 for this project :(